# Bash script to compare 2 files with different length strings

Tags: string, bash, for-loop

I have two files I am trying to compare the strings in each line by line.  File1 only contains a 6 character string prefix while File2 contains a 12 character string.  How can I loop through the File2 to find strings that start with the 6 characters from File1 and output those to a file?

#### File1

```
002379
005964
```

#### File2

```
002379ED6212
003354EB4591
004679BB2185
005964AB3379
005964DB5496
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk one-liner does what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a)if(substr($0,1,6)==i)print}' file1 file2
```

`NR==FNR` is only true for the first file. Each line of `file1` is stored as a key in the array `a`. `next` skips the other block. For each record in the second file, loop through each of the keys in `a` and compare the first 6 characters. If they are the same, print the record.

Output:

```
002379ED6212
005964AB3379
005964DB5496
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` might be able to achieve this

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$0]; next};substr($0, 1, 6) in a' File1 File2
```

Comment: No need for the semicolon after the `}` but apart from that, nice. I'm not sure why I used a loop!

Comment: @TomFenech, I am just playing it safe with the semi-colon based on "When awk statements within one rule are short, you might want to put more than one of them on a line. This is accomplished by separating the statements with a semicolon (‘;’). This also applies to the rules themselves." seen [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Statements_002fLines.html)

Comment: I think that only applies to statements within a block, not blocks themselves.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' file1) file2
```

It would be nice to just use `grep -f` to find all the lines in file2 that match a regex in file1, but you want to anchor the regexes in file1 to the beginning of the line.  So use the above to preprocess the strings by adding an anchor.

Answer (score 2):

For a pure-Bash solution . . . assuming you're using Bash v4.x, you can first populate an *associative array* whose keys are the lines of `File1`:

```
declare -A prefixes
while read prefix ; do
    prefixes[$prefix]=1
done < File1

# Now ${prefixes[002379]} is 1, and ${prefixes[005964]} is 1, but
# ${prefixes[anything-else]} is undefined.
```

And then check the first six characters of each line of `File2` to see if it's in this associative array:

```
while read word do ;
    prefix="${word:0:6}"
    if [[ "${prefixes[$prefix]}" ]] ; then
       echo "$word"
    fi
done < File2
```